# How to lock my monitor with command in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, locking

I want to lock my desktop with a shell command. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What desktop environment are you using?

Using `GNOME`:

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

Using `KDE`:

```
qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver Lock
```

Using `xfce`:

```
xflock4
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have xscreensaver installer this will work:

```
xscreensaver -lock
```

Other then that it is depending on which DE you have.